# PyTorch: Constant loss value and output within linear neural network

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, torch

I'm trying to make a neural network that calculates the right input angles for a rotation matrix. I'm having the classic linear network structure and at the last step the output is put into my function for the rotation, which returns a point in space as a list.

Here's the code I wrote for it:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable as V
import torch.optim as opt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


cam_pos = np.array([500, 160, 1140, 1])    # with respect to vehicle coordinates
img_res = (1280, 1080)

aspect_ratio = img_res[0] / img_res[1]

# in px
cx = 636 / aspect_ratio
cy = 548 / aspect_ratio

fx = 241 / aspect_ratio
fy = 238 / aspect_ratio

u = 872 
v = 423
D = 1900  # mm

img_pt = np.array([u, v, 1, 1/D]).T

camera_matrix = np.array([[fx, 0, cx, 0],
                          [0, fy, cy, 0], 
                          [0, 0,  1,  0],
                          [0, 0,  0,  1]])

class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Network, self).__init__()
        self.lin1 = nn.Linear(3,10)
        self.lin2 = nn.Linear(10,10)
        self.lin3 = nn.Linear(10,3)
        self.angle_list = []


    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.lin1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.lin2(x))
        x = self.lin3(x)
        self.angle_list.append(list(x.detach().numpy()))

        return torch.tensor(self.cam_function(x), requires_grad=True)


    def rot_x(self, alpha): 
        return np.array([  [1,                 0,             0, 0],
                        [0,     np.cos(alpha), -np.sin(alpha), 0],
                        [0,     np.sin(alpha), np.cos(alpha), 0],
                        [0,                  0,            0, 1]
    ])


    def rot_y(self, beta): 
        return np.array([  [np.cos(beta),  0,   np.sin(beta), 0],
                        [0,             1,              0, 0],
                        [-np.sin(beta), 0,   np.cos(beta), 0],
                        [0,             0,              0, 1]
    ])


    def rot_z(self, gamma):
        return np.array([  [np.cos(gamma), -np.sin(gamma),   0, 0],
                            [np.sin(gamma), np.cos(gamma),    0, 0],
                            [0,          0,                   1, 0],
                            [0,          0,                   0, 1]
        ])


    def cam_function(self, net_output):
        net_output = net_output.detach().numpy()
        x = net_output[0]
        y = net_output[1]
        z = net_output[2]
        
        rot_m = np.dot(self.rot_z(z), np.dot(self.rot_y(y), self.rot_x(x)))

        extrinsic_matrix = np.array([  [rot_m[0][0], rot_m[0][1], rot_m[0][2], cam_pos[0]],
                                        [rot_m[1][0], rot_m[1][1], rot_m[1][2], cam_pos[1]],
                                        [rot_m[2][0], rot_m[2][1], rot_m[2][2], cam_pos[2]],
                                        [0,           0,           0,           1         ]])

        cam_output = img_pt * D * np.linalg.inv(camera_matrix) * extrinsic_matrix / 1000
        cam_output = [cam_output[0][0], cam_output[1][1], cam_output[2][2]]

        return cam_output

model = Network()
loss_function = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = opt.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
target = torch.tensor([1.636, 1.405, 0.262]).float()
dummy_data = torch.tensor([0, 0, 0]).float()

losses = []
for epoch in range(5000):
    model.train()
    prediction= model(dummy_data)
    loss = loss_function(prediction, target)
    
    losses.append(loss.item())

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()

    optimizer.step()
```

And with that I'm getting a constant value of the loss and the output as well.

```
7.3858967314779305
tensor([7.9938, 3.9272, 1.8514], dtype=torch.float64, requires_grad=True)
7.3858967314779305
tensor([7.9938, 3.9272, 1.8514], dtype=torch.float64, requires_grad=True)
7.3858967314779305
tensor([7.9938, 3.9272, 1.8514], dtype=torch.float64, requires_grad=True)
```

Can someone help me please? If this works I would then extract the "angles" the NN used for the rotation matrix

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `numpy` in `cam_function`, use `torch.tensor`. Using numpy, the gradient does not flow when using backward.

Comment: Still not working, I replaced every numpy array with `torch.tensor` and also removed the `net_output.detach().numpy()`